# Calculate $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $(\vec{B} \times\vec{C})$ = $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{B}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{C}$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $\vec{A} = (1,2,3), \vec{B} = (3,-1,4), \vec{C}= (0,3,0) $

Calculate $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $(\vec{B} \times\vec{C})$ = $[\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{B}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{C}]$

I first calculate $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $(\vec{B} \times\vec{C})$ = $1 \times\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 4\\3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$-2 $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ + 3  $\begin{bmatrix}3 & -1\\0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

$=1(-12)-2(0) +3(9)$ = $15$

I then try to calculate $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{B}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{C}$, I know that $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{B}$ can be calculated as $a_xb_x+a_yb_y+a_zb_z$ I then try to similarly calculate $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{B}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{C}$ in the same way as $a_xb_xc_x+a_yb_yc_y+a_zb_zc_z$ = $(1\times3 \times0) + (2 \times -1 \times 3) + (3 \times 4 \times 0) = 0 +-6+0 = -6$

$-6\neq 15$,

but $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $(\vec{B} \times \vec{C})$ = $\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{B}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{C}$

So I'm assuming that I'm calculating the dot product wrong... Any solutions hints or tips??

Comment: How do you define $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}\cdot\vec{C}$?

Comment: I can't think of anything natural that $A\cdot B\cdot C$ could even mean, other than shorthand for $A\cdot(B\times C)$ which you already calculated. Is this notation defined somewhere in your lectures, notes, texts, etc?

Comment: It's from my applied calculus worksheet, no definition. Is there no such thing as dot product between three vectors?

Comment: What you have is the so-called "triple product."

Comment: No natural operation called a dot product between three vectors that I know of, no. But $A\cdot(B\times C)$ is called the triple product, so they may notate it as $A\cdot B\cdot C$ for whatever reason (it is an alternating trilinear operation, which is fairly multiplication-like).

Comment: $[\vec{A}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{B}$ $\cdot$ $\vec{C}]$ What if its in brackets like this? @ncmathsadist, what do you mean? I thought that the "triple product" is the one I worked out, the one on the LHS.

Comment: That is a common notation for triple product.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product): The equality you are trying to prove is just a definition. The point is that there is no triple dot product as you intended in your question.